# Empty SQL Files - PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, backup

So I'm trying to export my e-commerce database via PhpMyAdmin and it keeps downloading empty SQL Files. I'm 100% sure i'm selecting all my tables and I'm using the default sets when opening the export tab. It keeps coming out to 0 bytes. If needed i'll detail all the checkboxes I have checked in php my admin but not sure if it's needed.

Is my database too big? What's another way I can back up my database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)  on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Might be timeout or memory limit exceeded. Try [mySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/).  Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as OP - the exported `.sql` backup was always empty. Selecting the `gzipped` compression did the trick - hope this helps somebody else!

Answer (score 1):

Using mysqldump through ssh worked for me

Example

user: admin
password: pass123
database name: mydatabase

```
mysqldump --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --user=admin --password=pass123 mydatabase > backup.sql
```

Then I downloaded the file via FTP

Answer (score 0):

This could be a memory issue, increase the memory_limit in your php.ini file to 512M temporarily (assuming it is currently much less), restart required services for this change to take affect, and I am willing to bet this will now work for you... don't forget to change your memory_limit back when you are done.